# NodeJS wait for variable to be assigned from sql.get before continuing

Tags: node.js, sqlite, asynchronous, async-await

I know the sqlite (not sqlite3) module does requests in batches. I need to grab a value out of a database, assign it, then do some processing with it. However the function that fetches the value from the database isn't returning until after all the processing has taken place.

I need one of 3 things to happen:

1. The function to return right away
2. Halt the code until myEvent.id has been assigned
3. Make sql.get return right away

   ```
   myEvent.id = generateEventID();
   ///do stuff with myEvent.id

   function generateEventID() {
   return sql.get('SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name = "eventID"').then(row => {
     if (!row) return message.reply("a database error occured while generating an ID");
     currentID = row.intValue + 1;
     console.log("New eventID created: " + currentID);
     sql.run(`UPDATE settings SET intValue = ${row.intValue + 1} WHERE name =  "eventID"`);
     return currentID;
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Why don't you read the [manual](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)? node-sqlite3 does not support promises.

Comment: I did RTFM, you're confusing node-sqlite https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite
Which is a wrapper for sqlite that promisifies the use of callbacks. Which is useful in a language that uses promises.

With node-sqlite3
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/

The wrapper admittedly has extremely poor naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't return an `Id` straight away from the function because `sql.get(...)` is asynchronous.

One possible way to get around this would be to pass in a `callback` function as a parameter to `generateEventID()` and then make the caller to wait for the `callback` function to be invoked before progressing further.

Therefore your would look like this.

```
var doStuffWithEventId = function(eventId) {
    // Do more stuff.
}

generateEventID(doStuffWithEventId);


function generateEventID(callback) {
    return sql.get('SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name = "eventID"').then(row => {
        if (!row) return message.reply("a database error occured while generating an ID");
        currentID = row.intValue + 1;
        console.log("New eventID created: " + currentID);
        sql.run(`UPDATE settings SET intValue = ${row.intValue + 1} WHERE name =  "eventID"`);
        return callback(currentID); // Call function doStuffWithEventId with value of currentID variable
    });
}
```

This is one way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Side note here.

1. You generally would wait for the `update` operation to go through before returning anything.
2. You are anticipating that the Id would always be an incremental of 1. Databases don't always do that. So you can get caught off guard.
3. Your code assumes that the database operations are going to be always successful. You typically would want to handle potential exception that may raised when making external calls.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, your code should provide three main functionalities in a **particular order**:

1. Obtain a result from your data storage (SQL database in this case).
2. Perform a particular operation over the data obtained (referred as
   `//do more stuff`in your sniippet)
3. Perform an `UPDATE` query over your data storage.

Therefore, the implementation logic you provide is wrong as it fails to perform the three operations in that particular order. Don't forget that all Node calls are **asynchronous** by default and, in this case, you are failing to enforce the synchronization you need. To fix this, you should perform the following steps:

1. Obtain a result from your data storage. (Already done).
2. Perform a particular operation over the data obtained. This must be done inside the `sql.get()` callback or once the promise has resolved (since you are using promises in this case).
3. The method that performs operation over your data (i.e step 2) should return a new promise. Once this promise is resolved you will be able to call your `UPDATE` operation and in this way you will ensure that your implementation will meet all your requirements.

Now, this is how I would do it:

```
generateEventID();

function doMoreStuff(eventId){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //do your stuff
    if(err){
      reject(err)
    }else{
      resolve()
    }
  })
}

function generateEventID() {
  return sql.get('SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name = "eventID"').then(row => {
    if (!row) return message.reply("a database error occured while generating an ID");
    currentID = row.intValue + 1;
    console.log("New eventID created: " + currentID);
    doMoreStuff(currentID).then(function(){ //At this point your operations with currentId will have finished already
      sql.run(`UPDATE settings SET intValue = ${row.intValue + 1} WHERE name =  "eventID"`);
    });
  });
}
```

I really hope this helps!

Edit: Don't forget to implement the error handling for promises with `.catch()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to as `node calls`. I suspect you are trying to say "function calls". If that is true then it is incorrect. Not every function calls are `async`. If every single function call returns a promise, what you will find is that the application will run significantly slower than usual due to unnccessary context switch.

Comment: I meant node I/O calls since in this case we are dealing with SQL queries. Sorry I forgot to mention that, but those I/O calls are handled by service threads in an asynchronous way.